# Seeking help for the following sentence

Tags: grammar, questions

When we copy a file or a folder on computer, a notice will be appeared " 1 items are being moved"
Please kindly help to explain why it is items but not item as quantity always showing "1".
Hope you can understand what i mean.

Thanks

Comment: it’s because the programmers were lazy. Their choice was made based on the idea that using the s  (and the ’are’) makes it wrong for only one number and correct for all the others.

Comment: It’s the difference between writing: *printf(”%d items are being moved\n”, numItems)* and *printf(”%d item%s being moved\n”,numItems, numItems==1?” is”:”s are”)*

Comment: "1 item(s) being moved" is the convention. The UI expert is new, please bear with him.

Comment: Hello Jim. I understand what u mean but number 1 is fixed for every cases even if you are copying 10 items.

Comment: @Huyduc You mean it says "1 items are being moved" even if you're copying 10 items? That sounds like a programming fault or bug, and certainly nothing to do with the English language.